# C# Dropdown calendar for 1 year with MVC Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-mobile

New to razor and mvc, how to create a 1 year calendar in dropdown list starting from

```
var dt = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```

using two dropdowns ie. 1 for day and the other for month + year. for example
if i change the month + year ddl to "feb 2012" the day ddl must display 1 - 28 items
if change the month + year ddl to "jan 2012" the day ddl must display 1 - 31 items

Comment: Are you attempting to build a datepicker? - If so, you don't have to do this using dropdowns. you could use JQueryUI's datepicker and it will handle all this for you.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#default

Comment: @Kohan actually its a mobile web app, i have checked the jquery datepickers some of them do not work on opera mini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case this might help.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

I just viewed the demo on my mobile in opera mini and it worked great.

---

Alternatively if the drop downs are the way you want to go:

You could do it using jquery like so (Razor is not an issue here):

http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/drrHH/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery mobile has a datepicker.  Do not try and re-invent the wheel.